# BPF_KPROBE macro provides unexpected value of the syscall argument

Tags: ebpf, bpf

While playing with libbpf-bootstrap I'm getting unexpected (and strange) function argument for kprobe syscalls. For example for kprobe on `close` syscall with `int close(inf fd)` signature, I got enormous `fd` values like `fd=15761240` while expected small int like `fd=4`. Reproduced this on `Debian 11  x64 (kernel 5.10.0-7-amd64)` and `Ubuntu 21.10 x64 (kernel ~5.13)`.

Debug code:

```c
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

// accept4 syscall
// int accept4(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *restrict addr, socklen_t *restrict addrlen);
SEC("kretprobe/__x64_sys_accept4")
int BPF_KRETPROBE(accept, int ret) {
    u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    u32 pid = id >> 32;

    // filter specific pid for simplicity
    if (pid != 31114 || ret < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // debug returned file descriptor
    bpf_printk("opened pid=%d fd=%d", pid, ret);
    return 0;
}

// close syscall
// int close(int fd);
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_close")
int BPF_KPROBE(close, int fd) {
    u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    u32 pid = id >> 32;
    // filter specific pid for simplicity
    if (pid != 31114) {
        return 0;
    }

    // debug fd arg (expected to be equal to fd returned on accept4)
    bpf_printk("closed pid=%d fd=%d", pid, fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Results (see unexpected `fd=4` vs `fd=15761240` difference):

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe
            main-31114   [001] d...  9069.254408: bpf_trace_printk: opened pid=31114 fd=4
            main-31114   [001] d...  9069.321946: bpf_trace_printk: closed pid=31114 fd=15761240
```

I tried to alter `vmlinux.h`: at first with `vmlinux.h` delivered by libbbpf-bootstrap and then with "native" `vmlinux.h` from the instance OS kernel and on both ways I got the issue above.

Also tried to run the same bpf program in BCC way (compiled with bcc at run-time) with kprobes declared without BPF_KPROBE macro, like that:

```
int syscall__probe_close_entry(struct pt_regs *ctx, int fd) { ... }
```

and it worked as expected: `fd=4` at all the debug points.
Is it a BPF_KPROBE macro bug/incompatibility with the kernel or I'm missing something?

Comment: This is weird! Even without `BPF_KPROBE` directly using `PT_REGS_PARM1_CORE(ctx)` results in same `fd` value.

https://gist.github.com/nyrahul/5cb87f8c9a8e29046b3aa763b0b9633f

Also, with BCC it is working for me too!

Comment: Did you check the corresponding BPF bytecodes with `bpftool prog dump`? Maybe comparing the bytecodes for bcc and libbpf-bootstrap would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by @anakryiko [here](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap/issues/57)

That `__x64_sys_close()` actually has only one input parameter, and that's `struct pt_regs *`, which contains all the syscall input arguments. So you have to do something like this to get access to input arguments:

```c
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_close")
int BPF_KPROBE(do_sys_close, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
        pid_t pid;
        int fd;

        fd = PT_REGS_PARM1_CORE(regs);

        pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
        bpf_printk("KPROBE ENTRY pid = %d, fd = %d\n", pid, fd);
        return 0;
}
```

It might be a good idea to add syscall-specific kprobe/kretprobe macros, as this is a common gotcha. Added [libbpf/libbpf#425](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/issues/425) to keep track of that.